# Error when creating an Eclipse product configuration: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource cannot be found by org.eclipse.net4j.db

Tags: eclipse, h2, rcp, eclipse-emf, cdo-emf

I have created a CDO server using a Run Configuration which runs org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.product.tcp_h2 as a product. This works absolutely fine without any errors.

However, I have tried to create a product configuration which is based on this existing product which causes a:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource cannot be found by org.eclipse.net4j.db_4.3.0.v20140114-0640
```

I haven't made any changes between the run configuration and the product configuration.

Does anyone know the likely cause of the issue and why then product configuration isn't acting in the same way as the existing run configuration?

Comment: Most of the time this is caused by some plugins missing in your product. Did you set up a cdo.server.feature plugin and if you did: have you defined the plugins in feature.xml? It should contain org.h2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Calon had commented, the problem was due to missing plugins. I updated the meta-inf dependencies and it worked fine.